# Replace values in an nd numpy array at given axis index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to replace the values in a given numpy array (`A`) at a given index (e.g. `0`), along a given axis (e.g. `-2`) with a given value (e.g. `0`), equivalently:

```
A[:,:,0,:]=0
```

Problem is the input array `A` may come in as 3D or 4D or other shapes, so for 3D data I would need

```
A[:,0,:]=0
```

If it's 5D: `A[:,:,:,0,:]=0`

Currently I'm using an `exec()` to get this done:

```
slicestr=[':']*numpy.ndim(var)
slicestr[-2]=str(0)
slicestr=','.join(slicestr)
cmd='A[%s]=0' %slicestr
exec(cmd)
return A
```

I'm a bit concerned that the usage of `exec()` might not be quite a nice approach. I know that `numpy.take()` can give me the column at specific index along specific axis, but to replace values I still need to construct the slicing/indexing string, which is dynamic. So I wonder is there any native numpy way of achieving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use *Ellipsis* (see [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for more) to skip the first few dimensions:

```
# assert A.ndim >= 2
A[...,0,:]=0
```

---

```
A2d = np.arange(12).reshape(2,6)
A3d = np.arange(12).reshape(2,3,2)
A4d = np.arange(12).reshape(2,1,3,2)

A2d[...,0,:] = 0

A2d
#array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])

A3d[...,0,:] = 0

A3d
#array([[[ 0,  0],
#        [ 2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5]],

#       [[ 0,  0],
#        [ 8,  9],
#        [10, 11]]])

A4d[...,0,:] = 0

A4d
#array([[[[ 0,  0],
#         [ 2,  3],
#         [ 4,  5]]],  

#       [[[ 0,  0],
#         [ 8,  9],
#         [10, 11]]]])
```

Comment: Note to readers: Ellipsis works on python3.x only. For 2.x, you'd need to build a `slice` object.

Comment: Cool, that's I'm looking for! And it has nothing to do with python3 or 2, it is a numpy thing.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Which python 2.x are you using? It seems working for me on python 2.7.13 and numpy 1.12.0.

Comment: The `Ellipsis` object exists on 2.x as well, but the `...` syntax is invalid, at least on the version I'm using (2.7.10).

Comment: tested and worked in a conda env with `python=2.7.10` and `numpy=1.12.0`, also worked in `python=2.6.9` with `numpy=1.9.2`

Comment: @Jason Must be the conda env ;-) On my stock mac distribution, the `...` just doesn't work :-(